# Downloading PlayOnLinux

Tags: 12.04, playonlinux, curl, paint

I'm downloading PlayOnLinux to run Paint Tool SAI, but I cannot open PlayOnLinux. When I click on it to open it, a dialog box comes up that says: "PlayOnLinux cannot find curl (from cURL) You need to install it to continue". How do I install this?

I'm referring to this article: http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/292-ubuntu-paint-tool-sai-wacom-tablet-pressure

Comment: look at my answer , it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

It's saying you have don't have curl application installed, install it. Then you can continue your installation

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

then continue.